# What to do with unneeded streams from an external process?

Tags: java, exec, stdout, stderr

When I execute a command in a separate process, for example by using the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` method, whose JavaDoc states:

```
Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.
```

What do I need to do with the streams from this process, knowing that the process shall live until the Java program exists? (this is a detail but the Java program takes care of killing this process and the process itself has a safety built-in where it kills itself should it notice that the Java program who spawned him his not running anymore).

If we consider that this process produces no output at all (for example because all error messages and stdout are redirected to /dev/null and all communications are done using files/sockets/whatever), what do I need to do with the input stream?

Should I have one (or two?) Java threads running for nothing, trying to read stdout/stderr?

What is the correct way to deal with a long-living external process spawned from a Java program that produces no stdout/stderr at all?

**EDIT**

Basically I wrap the shell script in another shell script that makes sure to redirect everything to */dev/null*. I'm pretty sure my Un*x would be non-compliant if my "outter" shell script (the one redirecting everything to /dev/null) would still generate anything on *stdout* or *stderr*.  Yet I find it mindboggling that I would somehow be supposed to have threads running during the lifecycle of the app "for nothing".  Really boggles the mind.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is as you say, then you can probably ignore them.

However, rarely do things work out so cleanly. It may be worth it in the long run to spawn a single thread to pull stdout/stderr, just in case. The one day it fails and actually puts something out, is the day you needed to know what came out. 1 or 2 threads (I think it could be done with just one) won't be a large overhead. Especially if you are correct and nothing ever comes out of those streams.

Comment: Interesting. I'll edit my question...  Basically I wrap the shell script in another shell script that makes sure to redirect everything to */dev/null*.  I'm pretty sure my Un*x would be non-compliant if my "outter" shell script (the one redirecting everything to */dev/null*) would still generate anything on *stdout* or *stderr*.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r - I understand. I'm just one of those paranoid people. :) I do agree that the extra threads are probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way to deal with a process's input and output if you are not interested  in them is to close them promptly. If the child process subsequently tried to call read or write on stdin or stdout respectively, then an IOException would be thrown. It would be the responsibility of the child process to deal with the fact that it cannot read or write.

Most processes will ignore the fact that they cannot write and silently discard and writes. This is true in Java, where System.out is a PrintWriter, so any IOExceptions thrown by stdout are ignored. This is pretty much what happens when you redirect output to /dev/null -- all output is silently discarded.

It sounds like you've read the API on Processes and why it's important to read/write to the process if it expects to be doing any writing or reading of its own. But I'll reiterate, the problem comes that some OSes only allocated very limited buffers for (specifically) stdout, so it is important to either not allow this buffers to fill up. This means either reading any output of the child process promptly, or notifying the OS that you do not require the output of the process and that it can release any resources held, and reject any further attempted to write to stdout or read from stdin (rather than just hanging until resources become available).

Comment: thanks for the answer... It's not just that I've read it.  It's that I've read it and that I've been consistently bitten in the b**** when launching external processes from Java, over the years.  So now I'm taking quite a radical approach.  Actually I just thought of something else: my "outter" script does a "nohup", spawning itself another script immune to hangups/kill and whose streams have **nothing** to do with Java.  Hence from Java I can read/close/destroy the "outter" script after a while, knowing that the inner script will be invisible to Java :)

Comment: The child process is not necessarily a Java VM, so it cannot necessarily throw `IOException`.  For example it may receive `SIGPIPE`

Comment: @finnw I'm not sure what your point is. The JVM will receive the same SIGPIPE and throw an IOException when it gets one. What a process does when it receives a SIGPIPE is up to it. I believe programs like grep will exit if it receives a SIGPIPE, but firefox or vlc wouldn't care.

Comment: just to be exhaustive: I'm now "nohup'ing" and also forking using '&'.