# How would I run a separate jar file and set its console output?

Tags: java

I want to be able to run a separate jar file, and be able to display any output from its console, and be able to send input. I want to be able to create a console which will act like the console in windows 7, but look better.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to know how to convert your application to a jar, or how to run a separate jar from your application? Please explain exactly what you want to do with it.

Comment: I think it's clear what the OP is after. He wants to run a "separate" (=external) jar in a console that looks better than the one provided by the system (windows 7). For this he needs to be able to handle I/O of the external process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ProcessBuilder` to launch `java -jar yourprogram.jar` as follows:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "yourprogram.jar").start();
```

To deal with input / output of this process, you can follow this post:

- [Run external program concurrently and communicate with it through stdin / stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591215/run-external-program-concurrently)

Answer (score 0):

After finishing your code , create jar file output (It depends on which IDEA you are working on)

then you can use `java -jar JarFileName.jar` in order to run the jar file,

Note that JDK path should be defined in system environment to use `java -jar` command,